# Gensim doc2vec 300 dimensional vector fed into keras,lstm model not working.Loss is not diminishing

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

This is my code snippet:

```
model=keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(28,input_shape=(300,1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(14))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2,activation="softmax"))
sgd=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy)
model.fit(trainData,labeledData.sentiment,epochs=20,batch_size=3000)
```

trainData shape is [batch_size,300,1],when i begin training this model,loss is not going down.

Epoch 1/20
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s 89us/step - loss: 0.6927
Epoch 2/20
25000/25000 [==============================] - 0s 8us/step - loss: 0.6928
Epoch 3/20
25000/25000 [==============================] - 0s 8us/step - loss: 0.6928
Epoch 4/20
25000/25000 [==============================] - 0s 8us/step - loss: 0.6928
Epoch 5/20
25000/25000 [==============================] - 0s 8us/step - loss: 0.6928
Epoch 6/20
25000/25000 [==============================] - 0s 8us/step - loss: 0.6926

what am i missing?

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller batch size? 3000 is way larger than most of what I have seen being used in practice. A general [rule of thumb is a batch size smaller than 1000, or even less](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?lang=en). Also, you might want to experiment with different optimizers, like ADAM, or RMSPROP...

Comment: hi @dennlinger thank you for your time,yes i change the optimizer to "adam" batch size to 300, It  solved my issue.But can you  explain why it didn't work in the first place?And what difference it make when you change optimizer hyper-parameter? THANKS ALOT.

Comment: I think these are partially enough questions for a different post ;-) Note that most of the questions you just asked are better suited on [stats.se], or [datascience.se], and not on Stackoverflow. They are purely theoretical and thus off-topic on this site. I'll add an answer to this question ASAP so it becomes clearer what was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem lies in the large batch size, and - maybe also - in the optimizer used for the training.

It is hard to determine an exact reason why your algorithm did not converge with the current settings, but it can be argued as such:

### Large batch sizes have a slower convergence.

Counter-intuitively, training with larger batch sizes will actually in some instances slow down your training. The reason behind this is purely speculative and depends on the exact nature and distribution of your data. Generally, though, having a smaller batch size means having more frequent updates. If your calculated gradients all point in a similar direction, having these more frequent updates will lead to a faster convergence.
Good practice is to have a batch size that is *never* larger than 1000. In most scenarios 128 is a good rule of thumb and a nice trade-off between the speed advantage of larger batches, and the nice convergence properties of smaller batch sizes. Note that this only makes sense in cases where you have a lot of training data.

Also note that theoretically the gradients of multiple examples in that large setting can "average out", meaning the large batch size will have only a very small and indistinct gradient. Having fewer samples in a mini-batch will reduce this chance, although it increases the risk of "going the wrong direction" (i.e. having a gradient that points in the opposite directin).

### SGD is a good starting point, but there exist several optimizations.

One of these "smarter" variants is the suggested ADAM method. There is a highly cited [paper about it](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf), which can give you a vague idea of what happens under the hood. Essentially, SGD is a very naive solution that does not have any special assumptions or built-in optimizations.
(From what I know, ADAM for example uses first-order derivatives)

There exist many different ones, and there is a ton of [theoretical articles](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/) (and [practical comparisons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWzkRD6MjYI)) of the different implementations. It is worth a lot to at least understand partially what the parameters do, and know what values make sense to set them to.

For example, you already set the learning rate to a sensible value (0.001); personally, I usually end up with values between 0.001-0.01, and maybe use learning rate decay over time if I have larger learning rates.

Comment: ah,that explains it.Much appreciate.